# Importing all external modules into one file?

Tags: python, django

I am thinking of importing all external modules in one file and then importing from that file.  This way if/when I want to swap out an external module I can simply edit the one file.

Example directories:

```
# django project
...
app1
    imports.py
app2
    utils.py
app3
    utils.py
```

so in app1.imports.py I have

```
from app2 import utils as ALIAS
```

Then all my modules in app1 will import ALIAS from app1.imports.py.  This way if/when I want to use app3.utils I can simply make that one change in app1.imports.py

The problem is I don't know/understand python well enough to know if this is a good idea.  What are the pros and cons to doing this?  I don't see people doing this at all, so I'm guessing it's not a good idea? why?

Answer (score 0):

From Python documentation http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules:

> Modules can import other modules. ... The imported module names are placed in the
>   importing module’s global symbol table.

It is perfectly possible to import namespaces of all possible modules into a single module as aliases (ALIAS_1, ALIAS_2, ... ), and then import the namespace of the latter module whenever needed.

Let's take an example:

```
x.py    # Contains nothing

y.py    # Contains a single line which imports x as ALIAS
    import x as ALIAS

# Inside an interpreter session
>>> import x, y
>>> dir(x)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> dir(y)
['ALIAS', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> dir(x) == dir(y.ALIAS)
True
```

As long as you are not merging the imported module's namespace into the importing module's namespace, I don't see any side-effects.